# Why does this redirect not work?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect this directory power-supply-direct to this page /power-supply-direct

I am using this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/power-supply-direct(.*)$ https://www.example.com/power-supply-direct
```

in htaccess. If I type in `/power-supply-direct/sdfasdafs` it will redirect properly. But the actual page I am trying to redirect

```
/power-supply-direct/?___store=english/ProductList.aspx%253FCategoryID=5797
```

Will not redirect. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove query string from original string or just this specific query string `___store=english/ProductList.aspx%253FCategoryID=5797`?

Comment: I have a bunch like this but they all start with /power-supply-direct/?___store=english/ I am just trying to redirect all of them to a single page.